# How to listen to an action on a frame in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout, tkinter-text

I have a canvas on which I place a frame by the right-click. This frame contains several text widgets. I need to be able to delete a frame by the right-click but I can't find a way to bind a method to this frame or the text widgets.

Example of text widget inside the frame:

```
self.name = tk.Text(self.frame, width=self.width, height=1,
                            bg=self.backgroundColor, wrap=tk.WORD)
self.name.tag_configure("center", justify='center')
    self.name.tag_add("center", "1.0", "end")
```

Inside of the frame I place widgets using pack() method.

Here's my canvas:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("{}x{}".format(windowWidth, windowHeight))
root.title("UML")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=windowWidth, height=windowHeight, bg='white')
canvas.place(x=0, y=0)
```

Frames are placed on root like this:

```
self.frame.place(x=self.x, y=self.y, width=self.width,
                     height=self.height)
```

UPD:
here's how I bind canvas to make a menu for creating a frame:

```
canvas.bind("<Button-3>", popup)

def popup(event):
    global xToCreate, yToCreate
    print("popup")
    menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)
```

Comment: Research the `bind` method of widgets.

Comment: @BryanOakley I tried to bind the frame as I bind canvas to create this frame but it hadn't any effect. Could you provide some code?